# How to add User objects to manytomany fields?

Tags: django

I am trying to add the currently logged in user to a m2m field in my model:

```py
class(models.Model):
    name = m.cfield(...)
    admin = m.m2m(User, related_name="admin+",...)
    members = m.m2m(User, related_name="members+",...)
    creator = m.FKEY(User, related_name="creator+",...)
```

While I'm trying to create an object using this views:

```py
if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        clss = Class()
        clss.creator = user
        clss.admin.add(user)
        clss.members.add(user)
        clss.save()
        return redirect('...')
```

I am thrown with `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error.
The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\Desktop\Projects\gcepac\app\views.py", line 49, in new_classroom
    clss.admin.add(user)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 951, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 267, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\mowli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Any help?

Comment: Please post the original code for your model, don't rename the things just to make them shorter, that doesn't help, include as much information bas possible.

Comment: This what i have in my model. However, I've found the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error occurs here because, for a manytomany field, both the objects should have been saved in the db before relating it. While trying to save using `clss.admin.add(user)`, The user instance is already in the db, but not the current instance of `class` table.

So doing this worked!

```
if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        clss = Class()
        clss.creator = user
        clss.save()
        clss.admin.add(user)
        clss.members.add(user)
        clss.save()
        return redirect('...')
```